# Autoit: How to return just the cell/row of _Excel_RangeFind

Tags: autoit

I am trying to select a range, the range always starts at row 4 and then select a range until a value shows. The value im looking for is '**Total' I used _Excel_RangeFind to find the value in the workbook and it works, but I only want the cell. This way I can select from Row 4 until the value's row right above.
_Excel_RangeFind($oWorkbook, "**Total", "B:B", Default, $xlWhole)
I dont need any of the other items, just the row/cell. The range should be 4:Row above the value im looking for.

I tried to use _Excel_RangeFind. this found the value, but did not return just the cell. ArrayDisplay at least displayed the data, but I only need the cell/row

Comment: Return Value
Success: a two-dimensional zero based array with the following information:
    0 - Name of the worksheet
    1 - Name of the cell
    2 - Address of the cell
    3 - Value of the cell
    4 - Formula of the cell
    5 - Comment of the cell

Have a look at ADDRESS OF THE CELL!

Comment: $a = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'A4:' & $aResult[0][2])
_ArrayDisplay($a)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Excel.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

; Create application object and open an example workbook
Local $oExcel = _Excel_Open()
If @error Then Exit MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Excel UDF: _Excel_RangeFind Example", "Error creating the Excel application object." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)
Local $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookOpen($oExcel, "c:\Autoit\ForumTests\Excelsearch.xlsx")
If @error Then
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Excel UDF: _Excel_RangeFind Example", "Error opening workbook '" & @ScriptDir & "\Excelsearch.xslx'." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)
    _Excel_Close($oExcel)
    Exit
EndIf

Local $aResult = _Excel_RangeFind($oWorkbook, "**Total")
If @error Then Exit MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Excel UDF: _Excel_RangeFind Example 1", "Error searching the range." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)
_ArrayDisplay($aResult, "Excel UDF: _Excel_RangeFind Example 1", "", 0, "|", "Sheet|Name|Cell|Value|Formula|Comment")
$a = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'A4:' & $aResult[0][2])
_ArrayDisplay($a)
```

Excel looks like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you! it works, is there a way that you know to get the row above it. in your example **Total is at A18 is there a way to get A17?

Comment: Change the line to this to get the range from A4 to one cell abvoe the match. $a = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'A4:' & StringRegExpReplace($aResult[0][2], '\d', '') & (StringRegExpReplace($aResult[0][2], '\D', '') -1))